# Display div based on scroll up and div from current position

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on small application

i want to display the div if the **user scroll up to > 100px** from the current position 
and hide div if the **user scroll down to > 50** px  from current postion

example code

```js
myID = document.getElementById("myID");

var myScrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y >= 200) {
    myID.className = "bottomMenu show"
  } else {
    myID.className = "bottomMenu hide"
  }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
.bottomMenu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="bottomMenu hide"></div>
```

can any one help with code in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Finded the way to solve this

- first we want to get the scroll direction
- and create two counter 1.upcounter 2. down counter
- and if we start scroll up increase the upcounter and set down counter
  to 0
- and if we start scroll dow increase the downcounter and set up
  counter to 0
- if the up counter value reaches your value for example if reaches 100
  display the div
- and if the down counter reaches  your value for example if reaches 50
  hide the div

code example

```js
myID = document.getElementById("myID");

function showSmartMenu() {
    // current scroll position 
    var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    // scrolling up 
    if (st < lastScrollTop) {
        upCounter += 1;
        downCounter = 0;
        if (upCounter == 100) {
            myID.className = "bottomMenu show"
        }
    } else { // scrolling down
        downCounter -= 1;
        upCounter = 0;
        if (downCounter == -50) {
            myID.className = "bottomMenu hide"

        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
}
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var upCounter = 0
var downCounter = 0
window.addEventListener("scroll", showSmartMenu)
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}
.bottomMenu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="bottomMenu hide"></div>
```